# sp_replmonitorhelppublisher - "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

**Issue**:

I'm getting this error on Microsoft SQL Server 2008:

> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSload_tmp_replication_status, Line 80
>       An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

**Background**:

I'm trying to programmatically monitor replication status in Microsoft SQL Server. I'm using INSERT EXEC statement on **`sp_replmonitorhelppublisher`** to get the status, questions that will follow are not restricted to this proc, but I'm mentioning it because the proc is built-in, so I cannot rewrite it to get the data "the way it should be done". My (simplified) code to get the data is:

```
declare @t table (
    publisher nvarchar(max) null,
    distribution_db nvarchar(max) null,
    status nvarchar(max) null,
    warning nvarchar(max) null,
    publicationcount nvarchar(max) null,
    returnstamp nvarchar(max) null
)
insert into @t exec sp_replmonitorhelppublisher 'MY_PUBLISHER'
```

**Questions**:

I understand the MS SQL Server restriction that is causing the error, I guess that there is some INSERT EXEC statement somewhere inside the built-in proc. What I don't understand is:

1. Why it sometimes works without the error (I've seen it a couple of times run successfully)?
2. Why a workaround of running the same EXEC statement (not as part of INSERT EXEC) before the actual INSERT EXEC works without errors? I.e. this code works OK:

   ```
   declare @t table (
       publisher nvarchar(max) null,
       distribution_db nvarchar(max) null,
       status nvarchar(max) null,
       warning nvarchar(max) null,
       publicationcount nvarchar(max) null,
       returnstamp nvarchar(max) null
   )
   exec sp_replmonitorhelppublisher 'MY_PUBLISHER' -- extra call before main call
   insert into @t exec sp_replmonitorhelppublisher 'MY_PUBLISHER'
   ```
3. Is this workaround guaranteed to run without the error? And why?
4. Or is there some form of caching involved, that happens to be working for me, but is not guaranteed to work on every call?
5. Is there any better way of programmatically monitoring replication?

Comment: If you go to the System Stored Procedures node of the Management Studio tree, you can read the source code for the stored procedures in question. My guess would be that somewhere in the stored procedure, it's caching the information with an `insert...exec` command. If you want to carve your own monitoring of replication, then you can follow the code in `sp_replmonitorhelppublisher` and rework it to your own requirements.

Comment: I tried to follow the code of the proc, but it seems that there is some magic going on inside there: the `sp_replmonitorhelppublisher` calls  `distribution.sys.sp_replmonitorhelppublisherhelper` which I cannot find in the tree. Anyway, very useful hint. Thanks, @podiluska.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on the same issue - programatically monitoring replication status. I've found out that executing `sp_replmonitor*` stored procedures also updates the table `dbo.MSReplication_monitordata`. This table holds the current status information of replication.

So, my solution was to execute the `sp_replmonitorhelppublisher` and then read the values from the `dbo.MSReplication_monitordata`.

For example: Starting the publication and I waiting for it to finish (in a SQL Server Agent job) is done by this:

```
USE [DB]
DECLARE @StartDateTime datetime = GETDATE()
EXEC sp_startpublication_snapshot @publication='publ_DB'

USE [distribution]
DECLARE @Status int = 1

WHILE @status NOT IN (2, 6)
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
    EXEC sp_replmonitorhelppublisher
    SELECT @Status = status FROM dbo.MSReplication_monitordata WHERE publication='publ_DB' AND agent_type=1 AND time_stamp>@StartDateTime
END
```

Hope this helps!